# Javascript voting function doesnt work with two or more copies

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm looking to add multiple voting functions to my website. When you click the up or down icons the image should change colors and the text should change accordingly. I got it to work with one copy, but when I make a second or third copy it causes an error.

I'm a novice at javascript so any help will be appreciated.

jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghc9ox8j/ (note images not working)

This is the working Javascript:

```
<!--Weight Up or Down-->
$(document).ready(function() {     
  $('.weights').click(function() {
    $('img', this).attr('src', function(i, oldSrc) {
        return oldSrc == 'weightup.png' ? 'weightdown.png' : 'weightup.png';
    });
    $('.weightswitch').toggle(400);
    return false;
  });
});

    function showMessage(which) {
if (which == 1) {
document.getElementById("weightup").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("weightdown").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("average").style.display = "none";
}
else {
document.getElementById("weightup").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("weightdown").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("average").style.display = "none";    
}
}
```

This is the working copy HTML:

```
<div class="weightsystem">

<input name="weight" class="weightup"  type="radio" value="Yes" onclick = "showMessage(1)"/>
 <label class="weightup-label" for="weightup"></label>   

<!--Weight Number--> 
<div class="weightnumber">

<div id="weightup" style="display:none">Fat<span class="punctuation">!</span></div> 

<div id="average">Average</div>

<div id="weightdown" style="display:none"> Thin <span class="punctuation">!</span></div>

</div><!--End Weightnumber--> 

<input name="weight" class="weightdown" type="radio" value="No" onclick = "showMessage(2)"/>
<label for="weightdown"></label>
<p class="weightcounter">50-300</p>

</div><!--End Weight-->
```

And the CSS:

```
/*-------------weight------------------*/

 input.weightup[type="radio"]{
    opacity: 0; right:33px; margin-top:7px;
    position:absolute; cursor:pointer;
}
 input.weightup[type="radio"]+label{
    background: bottom center no-repeat; padding-left:40px; padding-bottom:10px;
}
 input.weightup[type="radio"]:checked+label{
    background:url(images/weightupall.png)top center no-repeat; padding-left:40px; padding-bottom:10px;
}

 input.weightup[type="radio"]:hover+label{
    background:url(images/weightupall.png)top center no-repeat; padding-left:40px; padding-bottom:10px;
}


 input.weightdown[type="radio"]{
    opacity: 0; right:33px; margin-top:-5px;
    position:absolute; cursor:pointer;
}
 input.weightdown[type="radio"]+label{
    background:url(images/weightdownall.png)top center no-repeat; padding-left:40px; padding-top:9px; 
}
 input.weightdown[type="radio"]:checked+label{
    background:url(images/weightdownall.png)bottom center no-repeat; padding-left:40px; padding-top:9px;
}

 input.weightdown[type="radio"]:hover+label{
    background:url(images/weightdownall.png)bottom center no-repeat; padding-left:40px;  padding-top:9px;
}


.weightnumber { color:#666; font-size:22px; margin:0; font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:42px; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:2px;  }

#average { font-size:15px; color:#999; }

#weightup { margin-left:-2px;}

#weightdown { margin-left:-2px;}

.punctuation { font-size:15px; margin-top:-3px; position:absolute; }

.contentarea { width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#CF3;  display:block; }

.weightcounter { position:relative; top:8px; color:#000; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; }


/*------Weightysytem----------*/
    .weightsystem {
        display: inline-block;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-top: 3px;
        border-left: #000 1px solid;
        border-bottom: #000 1px solid;
        width: 85px;
        text-align: center;
        height: 107px;
        float: right;
        position: relative;
    }
```

Comment: Make sure your IDs are unique.

Comment: `but when I make a second or third copy it causes an error.` what error?

Comment: And how are you adding a second copy? Are you changing the ids? If not, that's your problem. What you probably want to do is use classes

Comment: Yea, I changed the id's but when I click on one of the up arrows. It changes the text of only one of the copies.

Answer (score 0):

Can you spot any difference between the `if` and `else` branches in your code? I guess no, because your IDs are not unique and hence you're actually looking for the same DOM elements!

So, it would be a good idea to use the number after `weightup`, `weightdown` etc names.
For instance, like this

```
<input name="weight" class="weightup1"  type="radio" value="Yes" onclick = "showMessage(1)"/>
```

Then, in your code, calculate the ID dynamically.

```
function showMessage(which) {
   document.getElementById("weightup" + which).style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("weightdown" + which).style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("average"+ which).style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: I removed the if and else statements and replaced it with the code you posted, but now the text doesnt change when I select the up or down arrow .